# VBA - Document protection with exceptions

Tags: vba

we are using the protection function in word with "exceptions", so that users can only edit defined ranges. Is it possible to disable, or if not, to delete the exceptions ranges, so that we can have an final document at the end?

Usually we would use the protectiontype wdallowonlyreading, but this is the same as required for the exceptions.

```
If ActiveDocument.ProtectionType = wdNoProtection Then
    ActiveDocument.Protect Password:="", noReset:=False, Type:= _
        wdAllowOnlyReading, UseIRM:=False, EnforceStyleLock:=False
End If
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Cross-posted at: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/vba-document-protection-with-exceptions/6ac490e6-2ebc-4e37-9c52-ced19768b72f
and at:
https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/45435-vba-document-protection-exceptions.html
with answers in both locations.

For cross-posting etiquette, please read: A Message to Forum Cross-Posters http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184
The essence of Ken Puhl's message there is that cross-posting should be avoided but that when necessary, everyone should be aware of the cross-posting and it is your duty to make sure of that when you post. That saves time, effort and confusion.

"How to Post and When to Cross-Post
Admittedly, some posts do go without answers, and this is where the cross post can be beneficial. Just do it in the right way! My suggestion, for what it's worth, is to follow this series of events:

- Find one forum and stick with it, preferably a very busy one so you reach a bigger audience. If you don't get a satisfactory answer in a reasonable amount of time (days, not hours), then:
- Post in another applicable forum with your issue (1 or 2 other forums, not 20!).
- Include a link to your original post (see below).
- Make it very obvious that you have not got an answer to your question and are looking for more experts.
- Ask people to post their replies in the original forum.
- When it is solved, go back and mark it as such in all forums so that we're not chasing solved issues.

How to post a link:
On every forum I go to, the format to do this is the same, no matter which bulletin board software they use. I'm sure there will be some different, but for the majority, the steps to posting your link is as follows:

- Copy the URL (address) from your web browser.
- Enter it as text in your post as follows: [url]the url goes here[/url]
  i.e.[url][http://www.excelguru.ca/forums/showthread.php?259[/url]](http://www.excelguru.ca/forums/showthread.php?259%5B/url%5D)

That's it!"

Comment: For cross-posting guidelines on Stack Overflow read [answer]. _Provide context for links.
Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline._

Comment: @DavidBuck Would it be better for me to ignore the cross-post than to use an answer for this? I am editing to quote the relevant part. I am new here and trying to be a good contributor.